# Korah the "holy grandfather"

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, chassidic-rebbe, parshat-korach

Various online and written sources claim that various chassidic rabbis referred to Korah as "our holy grandfather". Some of these sources are mustered [here](http://arikahn.blogspot.com/2015/06/korah-holy-grandfather.html), but they're all very secondary sources.

Can anyone point to a more primary source for a rebbe who made this comment? (Eg written by the rebbe themeselves, or by a follower? At least something better than a modern drashah which just mentions in passing, "And so-and-so used to say...")